# Upgrade to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm iPhone developer. I want to upgrade my iphone to iOS 5. But I'don't know if I can run applications for iOS 4? Do I need to install new Xcode with new SDK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install iOS 5 using the beta SDK, or you can go through iTunes **Beta 10.5**.

I am sure iOS 4 apps will run on the Beta iOS 5. You may run into some crashes depending on what frameworks your app uses versus what frameworks have changed. This is a great opportunity to test your apps against iOS 5 and correct any issues.

But keep in mind it is still a **beta**, and an early one at that.

Comment: Agreed. Be sure to take a look at the Release Notes before installing it: there are definitely some bugs, and some of them fairly serious with the solution often being to wipe the content on the device and restore. In addition, Apple does *not* support reverting to iOS 4.x, so you want to be really certain. Me, if it was my day-to-day phone I'd stick with the simulator for a while, at least until one or two more builds come out.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Matthew.

Comment: Also take a look at the "Compatibility" forum in the iOS 5 Developer Forums: there are a number of important incompatibilities already listed in the 12 hours or so it's been available.

Comment: I just updated to iOS 5 and [wrote an article](http://techflipper.com/install-ios-5-beta-on-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-now-developers-only/) on how can you install it on your device.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the new beta sdk and then just install iTunes 10.5 beta and open iOS 5 beta file, it will open in iTunes and install on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..You need to get the latest SDK from the Apple developer portal with your username and password.
You will also get the iTunes beta but that shouldn't be of much use as long you use the simulator to try stuff out; but if you have the developer access, use the device instead.